# How making multi images in Owl carsoule plugin loop in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, carousel

I used Plugin of Owl carousel in vuejs but the first img only appear
i used this plugin
https://vuejsexamples.com/vue-component-for-owl-carousel-2/

```
<carousel autoplay= true  :nav= false :margin=1 :items=3 :autoWidth='false' :loop="false" >

    <template slot="prev"><span class="prev"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></span></template>

    <div class="item"><img src="../assets/imgs/header.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="../assets/imgs/header.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="../assets/imgs/header.jpg"></div>

    <template slot="next"><span class="next"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span></template>

</carousel>
```

Comment: Check your browser console: do you see any warnings? Errors?

Comment: No there is nothing related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem, I was making the direction of parent div as rtl so it was not working

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to debug it this way. Create a fiddle so we can help you better.